# how to close pycharm jupyter notebook data extraction

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, ipynb

I just had a weird problem: the one-dimensional array in jupyter notebook in Pycharm displayed multiple rows. I attached the image below. I know there is meaningless to discuss if it is a row or column when it is a 1d array. By the way, does anyone know how to turn off the data extraction? I would like to display the result as the second image shows.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1mdt.png)

what I expect is below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSIWL.png)

Really appreciate that if someone gives me a hint.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.